# ADD day month year quarter to a table based on a date column in the same table

Tags: sql-server, date, ssis

I have a table that contains a column date, I want to add to the the same table 4 other columns DAY, MONTH, YEAR, QUARTER based on the value of the column date for all the records in the table. How could it be done please ?

Comment: Please add an attempt you have made to your post. **HINT** Take a look at `DATEPART` [datepart-transact-sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Please include what you have [researched so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and why it didn't work for you.

Comment: Also a little ambiguous.    Sample data and desired results would be more helpful.   In the meantime think dateadd(DAY,1,datecolumn)

Comment: Is this question just a minor variation of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72887985/add-month-column-in-sql-server)?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 - computed columns via [datepart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
ADD TheYear = DATEPART(YEAR, DateColumn);

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
ADD TheQuarter = DATEPART(QUARTER, DateColumn);

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
ADD TheMonth = DATEPART(MONTH, DateColumn);

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
ADD TheDay = DATEPART(DAY, DateColumn);
```

This adds virtual, read-only columns to your table based on the value of your source column. This is likely the easiest, least approach unless you have not supplied all the relevant points.

Option 2 - Add columns

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
ADD TheYear int;

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
ADD TheQuarter tinyint;

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
ADD TheMonth tinyint;

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
ADD TheDay tinyint;
```

This is likely going to cause you pain as there is nothing ensuring the values stored in those 4 columns has any bearing on the value in your original Date column but it's an approach.

And since you're tagging SSIS, if you are trying to do this in a data flow - don't. Write the query to do it and bring this data into your pipeline

```
SELECT T.*
,   TheYear = DATEPART(YEAR, T.DateColumn);
,   TheQuarter = DATEPART(QUARTER, T.DateColumn);
,   TheMonth = DATEPART(MONTH, T.DateColumn);
,   TheDay = DATEPART(DAY, T.DateColumn);
FROM dbo.MyTable AS T;
```